# Cannot open chromium neither by the icon nor by the terminal, the following message appears:

Tags: apt, 20.04, permissions, chromium, sockets

`$ chromium-browser`

`error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snapctl: dial unix /run/snapd-snap.socket: socket: permission denied`

`Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`

I will remove and install again, maybe it solve the problem I guess. I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to learn the most I can, so If someone can explain how to solve and what that error means I will be grateful.

EDIT:

`$ sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser`

`E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 50938 (apt-get)`
`N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.`
`E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?`

I can't remove it too.

Comment: The second error means that another `apt-get` process is already running, perhaps unattended upgrades or another installation. However, your first error looks like you installed chromium via `snap`, in which case you'll have to uninstall it with `snap` instead of `apt-get`. If you are unfamiliar with Linux, the easiest way to uninstall it is probably using the graphical package manager that came with your distribution, e.g. Gnome Software if you installed standard Ubuntu.

Comment: Indicates that your snap daemon is not running. What is the output of `snap version`? Inspect the log: `journalctl -u snapd.service`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [See terminal text. 'Waiting for cache lock' error. How to fix? I'm on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352416/see-terminal-text-waiting-for-cache-lock-error-how-to-fix-im-on-ubuntu-21)