# See terminal text. 'Waiting for cache lock' error. How to fix? I'm on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, cache

```
advait@advait-Bravo-15-A4DDR:~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 43843 (synaptic)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 43843 (synaptic)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 43843 (synaptic)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 43843 (synaptic)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 43843 (synaptic)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 43843 (synaptic)
```

Comment: Another process `synaptic` is holding ownership of the lock file. Close the synaptic or kill it `sudo killall -9 synaptic` then re-run Your apt command. If that won't work and synaptic is already killed just remove the lock file `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` and re-run apt.

Comment: Check another workspace, or another window, you'll have started `synaptic` and caused the hold, and then forgotten about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close synaptic package manager, and the "sudo apt install" command will automatically continue.

You cannot have two different applications that work with the APT package management system open at the same time.

Yes, I very frequently see the same messages as you ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can force close the process by using the process id.

If your terminal says,

```bsh
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 43843 (synaptic)
```

Then, the process id in your case is **43843**.

To kill the process use this command,

```bsh
sudo kill 43843
```

Comment: Hello. Better to spend the effort to find what is holding lock and why.

Comment: @David Yes. I agree with you. I would recommend to wait until the process is done, rather than forced close the process.

Comment: use `sudo kill -9 43843`

Comment: Great answer. That simple.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390483/503930) on Unix & Linux SE by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) has some useful commands:

> If you want to kill processes based on their name or argument list, use pkill.
>
> ```
> pkill regexp
> ```
>
> Will kill all processes whose name matches the regexp extended regular
> expression.
>
> ```
> pkill -f regexp
> ```
>
> Will kill all processes whose list of arguments (including the first which usually contains the command name) concatenated with spaces matches the regexp.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately I have no idea what "regexp" or a regular expression is. I'll have to research.