# distribution upgrade stuck unattended-upgrades

Tags: upgrade, unattended-upgrades

My distribution upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 stuck at unattended-upgrades for about 20 minutes. Is it normal?
Do you have any suggestion, what should I do now? Do you have any suggestions?

I tried:
sudo dpkg --configure -a; sudo apt dist-upgrade -f

```
and it returned:

    dpkg: error: dpkg frontend lock is locked by another process
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 8680 (focal)... 21s
```

[image: distribution upgrade screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [See terminal text. 'Waiting for cache lock' error. How to fix? I'm on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352416/see-terminal-text-waiting-for-cache-lock-error-how-to-fix-im-on-ubuntu-21)